# Database error in django+mongodb objects.fiter with boolean field

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter, django-mongodb-engine

I am using **djongo** library to handle mongodb, but still getting database error while filtering queryset using a boolean field.

> Error: No exception message supplied,
> django.db.utils.DatabaseError

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
users = User.objects.filter(isVerified=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all django is a backend framework not mongodb libraray
secound of all you are using django orm which  doesn't support noSQL databases
right now django orm support only relational dbms
for handle mongodb [PyMongo](https://pypi.org/project/pymongo/) is a good library

Comment: I mentioned "djongo" not "django" actually. As django doesn’t support noSQL officially, that's why "djongo" is there to handle noSQL. djongo = django+mongo

Comment: oh my bad, but i still recommend pymongo over djongo because django orm structure which djongo is using is not good for non relational databases
i tried it with elasticsearch and i want't  satisfied